# Hamburger icon click not working in Drawer Layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am implementing `Navigation drawer` in my app. Everything is working fine. I have one issue when I click on `Hamburger icon` the navigation drawer does not open. After that if I swipe then the navigation drawer opens successfully. After swipe back I can successfully close the navigation drawer. Now the Hamburger icon click is working properly and I can open the navigation drawer by clicking on the icon.

So I take help of `Log`

**here is some code**

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    Log.e("drawer 1","clicked");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.e("drawer 2","clicked");
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });



 private void setUpNavigationView() {
        int[][] states = new int[][]{
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}  // pressed
        };

        int[] colors = new int[]{
                Color.BLACK,
                Color.RED,
                Color.GREEN,
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.WHITE

        };

        ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(states, colors);

        navigationView.setItemTextColor(csl);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.nav_home:

                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_fav:
                        if (sharedPreferences.contains("favHotelId")) {

                            searchNearHotel("favHtl");
                        }
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No favorite hotels",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_sign_out:                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                }
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                loadHomeFragment();

                return true;
            }
        });

        final ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle  = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
               // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                drawer.openDrawer(drawerView);
                Log.e("drawer 3","clicked");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up


        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
         tv_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.drawer_userName);
        drawer_userNameEmail = (TextView) 
        }
    }
```

When I click on the icon for the first time the  `public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)` method isnt called that's why my drawer is not opening. After `swipe gesture`  on the navigation drawer the method is successfully called.

Please help me to find out where the issue is.

Comment: Show ur log details corresponding to first time click.

Comment: Please provide full code regarding navigation drawer

Comment: on first time click only `drawer 2 clicked` show in Log and after swipe `drawer 3 clicked` also show in Log @Neo

Comment: R U using android studio?@GhanshyamSharma

Comment: Yes I am using Android studio 2.3@Neo

Comment: Then why r U not using predefined navigation drawer template..@GhanshyamSharma

Comment: so what should i use@Neo

Answer (score 2):

Override this method in your `Activity`

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //return true for ActionBarToggle to handle the touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create your navigation drawer using android studio template.

follow this flow:

```
 fileMenu-->new-->newProject-->configure your new project-->select navigation drawer activity-->next/finish
```

Here are some ref. for demonstration:

[navigation 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju837bQOBfg)

[navigation 2](http://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial)